# Request fails in pythonanywhere

Tags: python

My code is working perfectly in localhost. After uploading my code in Pythonanywhere my code is not working anymore.
After investgation, I understood that reponse.status_code is not working properly. Here is my code:

```
def getDataAndStore(url):
  reponse = requests.get(url)
  if reponse.status_code == 200:
     print("got info")
```

I expect the "got info" to be printed but it doesn't work. If I bring the print statement out of if condition it prints the "got info". This piece of code is working in my pc.what is the mistake?

Comment: You're not getting a 200 status code so your print statement  isn't being executed

Comment: Hi it works on my local pc any setting must be done in pythonanywhere?

Comment: First step is to print the status_code so you can see its value.

Comment: it is 403 but why is different? it is a forbidden error but how come I can access through my local PC

Comment: what is your pythoanywhere plan? if you have free plan these are whitelisted sites that you can access https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- @buran is completely correct.  We can add sites to the whitelist if they are official public APIs -- just send us a link to the API documentation.

Comment: @GilesThomas Thanks for the information. So as I am using a free plan, can I request the following URL (http://osdemo.ir/) be considered in the whitelist? If yes, how? ( I should send an E-mail to them)

Comment: Yes, just send an email to support@pythonanywhere.com.  It will need to be an official documented API, though, so include a link to the API documentation.